# "Message: maxItemsToDisplay is not defined" error message

Tags: javascript, magento, magento2, magento2.1

after upgrading to Magento 2.1.8, I start getting this:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "if: function (){return getCartParam('summary_count') }"
Message: Unable to process binding "if: function (){return maxItemsToDisplay < getCartLineItemsCount() }"
Message: maxItemsToDisplay is not defined
    at if (eval at createBindingsStringEvaluator (/pub/static/frontend/grand/grand1/en_US/knockoutjs/knockout.js:2624), <anonymous>:3:55)
    at ko.computed.disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved (/pub/static/frontend/grand/grand1/en_US/knockoutjs/knockout.js:3989)
    at evaluateImmediate (/pub/static/frontend/grand/grand1/en_US/knockoutjs/knockout.js:1737)
    at Object.ko.computed.ko.dependentObservable (/pub/static/frontend/grand/grand1/en_US/knockoutjs/knockout.js:1946)
    at init (/pub/static/frontend/grand/grand1/en_US/knockoutjs/knockout.js:3988)
    at /pub/static/frontend/grand/grand1/en_US/knockoutjs/knockout.js:2989
    at Object.ignore (/pub/static/frontend/grand/grand1/en_US/knockoutjs/knockout.js:1249)
    at /pub/static/frontend/grand/grand1/en_US/knockoutjs/knockout.js:2988
    at Object.arrayForEach (/pub/static/frontend/grand/grand1/en_US/knockoutjs/knockout.js:151)
    at applyBindingsToNodeInternal (/pub/static/frontend/grand/grand1/en_US/knockoutjs/knockout.js:2974)
```

please help

Comment: The message says "maxItemsToDisplay is not defined" ... Did you verify that maxItemsToDisplay is either in the current binding context or available as a global variable? Maybe the update introduced a new knockout version - there have been subtle changes with the handling of  binding context changes in knockoutjs in the past. Especially from version 2 -> 3 there have been non backward compatible changes.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to do this already:

1. [Delete folder] pub/static/frontend/[theme]
2. [Delete folder] var/cache
3. [Delete folder] var/view_preprocessed
4. run command: `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production`
5. run command: `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: 1. Done
2. Done
3. Done
4. Generating an error:
Something went wrong while compiling generated code. See the error log for details.
Command returned non-zero exit code:
`/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/bin/php -f /home/sas/public_html/bin/magento setup:di:compile`

5. Done

Comment: Well, and did you check the ERROR log for details?